# How can I add all contents of a dynamic html table to a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jquery, html, json

So my table is 1 row where rows can be added, although it does not have unique id's for each row. I'd imagine this is the issue.

```
 $('#submitdata').click(function(){
var table = document.getElementById('tableAc');

var rowLength = table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

    var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.myList_x005f_ListListItem' },
    "OData__x0065_c91": $("#Select1").val(),
    "selectn": $("#SelectNumb").val(),
    "sSurname": $("#spSurname").val(),
    "JointAC": $("#checkboxAC").val(),
    "firstName": $("#spFirstName").val(),
    "mobile": $("#spMobile").val(),

      };
         $.ajax({
                   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items",
                   method: "POST",
                                 data: JSON.stringify(data),

                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), },

                   success: function (data) {
                              alert('Item added successfully');
                  },
                  error: function (error) {
                      alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
                 }
          });

}


});
});
```

This is my addrow function -

```
   $('#AddAccountRow').click(function () {
                   document.getElementById("tableAc").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td>Mycolumn</td><td>Mycolumn2</td>..etc'(html row);

Each row that gets added has the same ID. When I click to run the function "submitdata" it only adds the first row
```

Comment: SharePoint Online allows you to use JSON Light.  So instead of dealing with the `__metadata : { type : 'SP.Data.myList_x005f_ListListItem' }` business, you can simply set the metadata you need to, and change the `odata=verbose` to `odata=minimalmetadata` or `odata=nometadata`.

Comment: In your submitdata click event you have used table with ID 'myTable' and in addrow function you are using table with ID 'tableAc'. Ensure you are getting the proper rowcount in your rowLength variable. Also SharePoint will automatically generate item ID for newly created items, so we need not worry about your HTML table not having unique row IDs.

Comment: Hi, yes I fixed that but still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a form in a Sharepoint page.

In that form, there's some fields to complete, like `first name`, `surname`, `mobile`...

When you click **AddAccountRow**, the values entered in your form are inserted into a table **tableAc**.

Then, when someone pressed the **submitdata** button, all data inside the table **tableAc** are posted to a Sharepoint list.

I created this code in my Sharepoint environment and it works.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AddAccountRow').on('click',function () {
      $('#tableAc').append('<tr><td>'+$('#spSurname').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#spFirstName').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#spMobile').val()+'</td></tr>');
    });

    $('#submitdata').on('click',function(){
      $('#tableAc tbody tr').each(function(){
          var spSurnameVal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(0)').text();
          var spFirstNameVal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
          var spMobileVal = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
          var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.MyListListItem' },
            "spSurname": spSurnameVal,
            "spFirstName": spFirstNameVal,
            "spMobile": spMobileVal,
          }; 

          $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: { 
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 
            },
            success: function (data) {
              alert('Item added successfully');
            },
            error: function (error) {
              alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
            }
          });   
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div>
  <label>Surname</label><input type="text" id="spSurname"><br>
  <label>First Name</label><input type="text" id="spFirstName"><br>
  <label>Mobile</label><input type="text" id="spMobile"><br>
  <a id="AddAccountRow" style="border:1px solid #000;">Add account row</a><br>
</div>

<div>
  <table id="tableAc">
    <thead>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <a id="submitdata" style="border:1px solid #000;">Submit data</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the data is actually inputted into the dynamic table and then the user can add rows to add extra information. Once it is all entered, they can then submit all the data. I'll check out your answer now, thanks

Comment: As in  no row gets saved when Addrow is pressed. it just adds an extra row to add another user

Comment: Hi can you look at my newest question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258426/how-can-i-get-my-dynamic-table-to-update-a-sharepoint-list-with-ajax